# PolymerJS 1.0 : How to get properties of dynamically created component?

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

```
<dom-module id="element-1">
    <template>
        <input type="text" value={{title}}>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            properties: {
                title: {type: String}
            }
        })
    </script>
</dom-module>


<dom-module id="element-2">
    <template>
        <element-1></element-1> // Added dynamically using javascript.
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            properties: {
                property_1: {type:String}
            }, 
            // Here, I can access property_1 by this.property_1
            // How to get the property of element-1(title) here?
        })
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

So, basically, I have a component (element-2). Inside that component I dynamically add another element (element-1). Now, how the I read the properties of element-1 from element-2?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Please show your failed attempts so that we can help with your specific issue

Comment: Tomasz, the answer I needed was exactly the same given by @tony19. Thanks for your concern buddy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polymer has an [instance method](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/instance-methods#instance-methods) to query its local DOM:

> `$$(selector)`. Returns the first node in this element's local DOM that matches `selector`.

With this method, you could use `this.$$('element-1').title` from `<element-2>`.

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.5.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
</head>
<body>
  <element-2></element-2>

  <dom-module id="element-1">
    <template>
      <span>{{title}}</span>
    </template>
    <script>
      HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
        Polymer({
          is: 'element-1',
          properties : {
            title: {
              type: String,
              value: "Hello world!"
            }
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
  
  <dom-module id="element-2">
    <template>
      <div id="container"></div>
    </template>
    <script>
      HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
        Polymer({
          is: 'element-2',
          addElement1: function() {
            var e1 = document.createElement('element-1');
            this.$.container.appendChild(e1);
          },
          ready: function() {
            this.addElement1();

            var e1ref = this.$$('element-1');
            console.log("this.$$('element-1').title:", e1ref.title);
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

<sup>[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/xOZyJL?editors=1001)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much @tony19 That $$ was the stuff I was missing.

Comment: @ArunKumarP, No problem :)